# Python and mongoDB connection pool ( pymongo )

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a web application, and there are thousands of requests every minutes.
the following is my python code for mongoDB connection:

Tool.py:

```
globalconnection = None

def getCollection(name,safe=False,readpref=ReadPreference.PRIMARY):

    global globalconnection
    while globalconnection is None:
            try:
                    if not globalconnection is None:
                            globalconnection.close()
                    globalconnection = Connection('mongodb://host:port',replicaSet='mysetname',safe=False,read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY,network_timeout=30,max_pool_size=1024)
            except Exception as e:
                    globalconnection = None

    request_context.connection = globalconnection

    return request_context.connection["mydb"]["mycoll"]
```

web.py

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    request_collection = getCollection("user")
    results = request_collection.find()
    for result in results:
        #do something...
        request_collection.save(result)
    request_collection.end_request()
```

One http request gets the connection through this function,

and the http request calls end_request before the end of the request.

But I found that there are many AutoReconnect errors and over 20000 connections in mongoDB while increasing requests.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is unrelated, but it's more common to say `if x is not None:`.

Comment: not to mention that globalconnection cannot be not None on that line since we just got there past "while globalconnection is None:"

Comment: Because there would be several requests go into "while" in the same time, I add "if" to reduce the numbers of Connection object

Comment: As Asya said, the while loop will stop when the globalconnection is None, that means inside the while loop globalconnection will always be false. is not a do-while loop

Answer (score 2):

1. For auto-reconnection you simply catch the exception, and try to get the connection again:
   http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html
2. 30 secs timeout sounds too long for, try shorter timeout instead?
3. Increase max number of connection from mongodb (default:20000)
   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections

Comment: 1. Thank you for your suggestion, and I have implemented it. 2. do you  have any suggestion?  3. I have no idea about this because there is a limit of 20,000 connections in mongoDB accroding to this [website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Too+Many+Open+Files)